# "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object" Laravel - Auth::id() command

Tags: php, laravel

This is a sample of my code from DatatablesController.php

```
$id = Auth::user()->id;
   $data = Cdr::
      select('src','dst','start','duration','billsec','disposition','uniqueid')
      ->where('billsec','>', '0')
      ->where('start','>=',Carbon::today())
      ->join('alt_portal.numbers', 'nr','=','dst') 
      ->where('alt_portal.numbers.user_id','=',$id)
      ->get();
```

I am doing Laravel project in which will be a lot of users. And each user has it's own number or numbers. Basically, I am trying to select from database only those numbers which belong to specific user, in other words, to logged in user's ID, because user can only see his/her outgoing and incoming calls in the table.

And when I am trying to do this:

```
$id = Auth::user()->id;
...
->where('alt_portal.numbers.user_id','=',$id)
```

I get a message in browser, which corresponds to an error:

> message: "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"

Does anyone know how to correct this issue?

P.S. I am new to Laravel.

Comment: make sure you are logged in while accessing `Auth::user()->id`

Comment: Yes, I am logged in. I tried to print my ID in blade.php file and it worked, I got my ID showing in the page.

Comment: paste your route here how you are calling your route?

Comment: Route::get('/api/datatables', 'DatatablesController@Data')->name('api.datatables.index');

Comment: have your used the Auth facade , `use Auth;` ? try `dd(Auth::user()->id());` and check whether you get your id.

Comment: Yes, I am using Auth facade and dd(Auth::user()->id()); did not help, getting same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case closed. Thank you guys for you responses! I managed to fix my problem.

I found solution here: [ANSWER](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/authuser-returns-null-in-laravel-52)
But I added stack directly to middleware, not in the 'web' group.

This is my /Http/kernel.php file:

```
protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class
    ];
```

Comment: i would recommend leaving the middleware groups as-is, otherwise you are loading the auth middleware for every request by putting it in the global stack.  move your route to routes/web.php instead and you will load that middleware automatically.